# Deezer player.seek not working

Tags: javascript, deezer

i am trying to load a song and make it start playing from second 30.I use dz.player.playtracks(); and then dz.player.seek(30); but still starts from the beginning.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to use the offset instead. Here's an example,

// Index and offset parameters set to start playing from first track at '22 in play queue
DZ.player.playTracks([3135556, 1152226], 0, 22);